# On running elassandra distribution on windows10 (not on docker) ElasticSearch localhost:9200 not reachable

Tags: elassandra

I downloaded Elassandra distribution from https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/releases 
made chanes in elasticsearch.yml file as below and starting elassandra giving "cassandra -f" (also tried "casandra -e" which give error option -e not recognizable)
Cassandra starts but elastic search is not reachable on localhost:9200
Please help and suggest 
Note: i am not running elassandra on docker but in windows10 using its executables bat

i do not want to run elassandra in docker i tried docker image it runs fine.

below is then elasticsearch yml config:-

```
cluster.name: 'Test Cluster'
node.name: node-1
node.attr.rack: r1
path.data: C:/Users/zia/.cassandra/DemoCluster3/node2/elas/data
path.logs: C:/Users/zia/.cassandra/DemoCluster3/node2/elas/logs
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
```

Cassandra is getting started but elastic search is not reachable on localhost:9200 .
Please help and suggest

trying to run elassandra distribution in windows 10 using its executable .i do not want to run it as docker image. Elassandra docker image is working fine

Comment: i guess elassandra is not supported on Windows so far, i am also looking into it to get it run quickly.